# Logged In user switching to another user in PHP session

Tags: php, mysql, session

My problem is that when I login as user 1, I can see users 1 info for about 1-2 pages but when I go to another page or refresh the page I'm logged in as another user (user 2). But if I log in as user 2 everything is okay. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my login script.

```
<?php
// This is the login page for the site.
require_once ('../includes/config.inc.php'); 
// Set the page title and include the HTML header.
$page_title = 'Page Title';
include ('../includes/header.php');

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "some", "some", "some");

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    $url = BASE_URL . 'index.php'; // Define the URL.
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Quit the script. 
}

//HTML Purifier  
require '../htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
//End HTML Purifier

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { // start of submit conditional.
    require_once (MYSQL);
    
    // Validate the username or email address:
    if (!empty($_POST['login']) && strlen($_POST['login']) <= 255) {
        $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $purifier->purify(strip_tags($_POST['login'])));
    } else if(!empty($_POST['login']) && strlen($_POST['login']) >= 256) {
        $e = FALSE;
        echo 'Error';
    } else {    
        $e = FALSE;
        echo 'Error';
    }
    
    // Validate the password:
    if (!empty($_POST['pass']) && strlen($_POST['pass']) <= 255) {
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['pass']);
    } else if(!empty($_POST['pass']) && strlen($_POST['pass']) >= 256) {
        $p = FALSE;
        echo 'Error';
    } else {
        $p = FALSE;
        echo 'Error';
    }
    
    if(($e != FALSE) && ($p != FALSE)) { // check pass
        $pass_salt = "SELECT users.password, users.salt FROM users JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id WHERE (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') AND users.active IS NULL";
        $ph = mysqli_query($dbc, $pass_salt) or trigger_error("Query: $pass_salt\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ph)){ 
            $password = $row['password'];
            $salt = $row['salt'];
        }

        if(!empty($salt)) {
            $sha512 = hash('sha512', $p . $salt);
        }

        if(!empty($password) == !empty($sha512)){
            $user_pass = TRUE;
        } else {
            $user_pass = FALSE;
        }
    }
    
    if(isset($user_pass) && ($user_pass == TRUE) && !empty($salt)) { // If everything's OK.
        $q = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, users.user_level FROM users JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id WHERE (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') AND users.password = '" . $sha512 . "' AND users.active IS NULL";        
        $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    
        if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {

            // Register the values & redirect:
            $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
            // check if user is logged in then update the old login date
            $u = "UPDATE users JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id SET users.last_login = NOW(), users.deletion = 0, users.deletion_date = NULL WHERE (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "') AND users.password = '" . $sha512 . "' AND users.active IS NULL"; 
            // save the info to the database
            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $u);
            mysqli_free_result($r);
            mysqli_close($dbc);
                            
            $url = BASE_URL . 'home/'; // Define the URL:
            header("Location: $url");
            exit(); // Quit the script.
                
        } else { // No match was made.
            echo 'Error';
        }
        
    } else { // If everything wasn't OK.
        echo 'Error';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
?>
```

Here is my logout script.

```
<?php
ob_start(); // Start output buffering. // This is the logout page for the site.
session_start(); // Initialize a session.

require_once ('../includes/config.inc.php'); 
$page_title = 'Title';

// If no user_id session variable exists, redirect the user:
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    $url = BASE_URL . 'index.php'; // Define the URL.
    ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Quit the script.
    
} else { // Log out the user.

    $_SESSION = array(); // Destroy the variables.
    session_destroy(); // Destroy the session itself.
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 2592000, '/'); // Destroy the cookie.

}

$url = BASE_URL;
ob_end_clean();
header("Refresh: 3; $url");
include ('../includes/header.php');

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "some", "some", "some");

include ('../includes/footer.php');
exit(); // Quit the script.
?>
```

And here is what I have in header.

```
ob_start();// Start output buffering.
session_start();// Initialize a session.
```

Here is the very top part of the home page.

```
// Set the page title and include the HTML header.
$page_title = 'Title';
include ('../includes/header.php');

// Include the configuration file for error management and such.
require_once ('../includes/config.inc.php'); 
require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "some", "some", "some");

// If no user_id session variable exists, redirect the user:
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

    $url = BASE_URL . 'index.php'; // Define the URL.
    ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Quit the script. 
}
```

Comment: about 3 active users and 50 unactive users.

Comment: @Tags, Is User 1 and User 2 correlated somehow? Are they both admins? Is User 2 having user id = user id of User 1 -+ 1?

Comment: Only user 2 is an admin.

Comment: Are you talking about user level normal users have a value of 0 and  admins have a user level of 1

Comment: I'm talking about your IDs in the database. Don't you use an auto-increment ID to have an unique user id?

Comment: yes i do user one is 1 and user two is 2 and so on.

Comment: Perfect. "Normal users have a value of 0 and admins have a user level of 1", The code seems not wrong but what you posted here got me an idea: Value "0" is interpreted by PHP as "false", that could cause something really bad. I'd suggest you to set "normal" users value to 2 instead. Could you try that for me?

Comment: I still get the same problem :(

Comment: Have you looked at what the session IDs are throughout all these requests. if user #1 has session ID 'a', and user #2 has session ID 'b', check if user #1's session ID changes to 'b' when the "crossover" occurs.

Comment: @Marc B yes they switch.

Comment: @TaGs could I test it by my self? Have you have a domain or a localhost access to provide to me?

Comment: @Charliepiga I do not have permission to give that info out :(

Comment: @TaGs, I do not want your code, I just want to be one of these users. I have no interest on destroy anything or hack anything (well... if you are working for a banking company I'd not trust of myself to be honest)...

Comment: I was reading some where on SO cant remember the url that it can have something to with the php.ini file?

Comment: @Charliepiga its still a no go, I wish I could but cant, sorry about that.

Comment: @TaGs, That's ok. I understand it. Could you please tell me in which page the User actually change?

Comment: It can be any given page after the login script redirects the user to the home page and this error will occur.

Comment: @TaGs, What about the home page script? Is it classified too?

Comment: I posted the very top of the home page.

Comment: Can you post the output of `$_SESSION`, particularly after the page refresh when you can see both user's info?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I think I see is that if user1 and user2 both have the same email address and same password, you'll log them both in.

```
...WHERE
    (contact_info.email = '" . $e . "' OR users.username = '" . $e . "')
AND
    users.password = '" . $sha512 . "'
AND
    users.active IS NULL"
```

This may not be your problem, though, as that should show up immediately, not after refreshing the page, but you may want to consider it.